# What is AttributeSet and how can i use it?

Tags: android, attributes, view

What is AttributeSet in Android?

How can i use it for my custom view?

Comment: @oae that link is broken

Answer (score 34):

A late answer, although a detailed description, for others.

**AttributeSet (Android Docs)**

> A collection of attributes, as found associated with a tag in an XML document.

Basically if you are trying to create a custom view, and you want to pass in values like dimensions, colors etc, you can do so with `AttributeSet`.

### Here's an example

Imagine you want to create a `View` like below

[image]

There's a rectangle with yellow background, and a circle inside it, with let's say 5dp radius, and green background. If you want your Views to take the values of background colors and radius through XML, like this:

```
<com.anjithsasindran.RectangleView
    app:radiusDimen="5dp"
    app:rectangleBackground="@color/yellow"
    app:circleBackground="@color/green" />
```

Well that's where `AttributeSet` is used. You can have this file `attrs.xml` in values folder, with the following properties.

```
<declare-styleable name="RectangleViewAttrs">
    <attr name="rectangle_background" format="color" />
    <attr name="circle_background" format="color" />
    <attr name="radius_dimen" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Since this is a View, the java class extends from `View`

```
public class RectangleView extends View {

    public RectangleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RectangleViewAttrs);
        mRadiusHeight = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RectangleViewAttrs_radius_dimen, getDimensionInPixel(50));
        mCircleBackgroundColor = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RectangleViewAttrs_circle_background, getDimensionInPixel(20));
        mRectangleBackgroundColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.RectangleViewAttrs_rectangle_background, Color.BLACK);
        attributes.recycle()
    }
}
```

So now we can use, these properties to our `RectangleView` in your xml layout, and we will obtain these values in the `RectangleView` constructor.

```
app:radius_dimen
app:circle_background
app:rectangle_background
```

Comment: why did you provide an  integer value in  `getDimensionInPixel(50)`?

Comment: Thanks for pretty answer it can be understandable easily. To contribute this answer, need to give a small information which will be more useful.  Recycle the TypedArray after you have done. Which will make it to be re-used by later caller.

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru Good suggestion, I've made the change.

Comment: @capt.swag can we use attributeSet to get the basic values like `layout_width` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use AttributeSet to get extra, custom values for your view which you define in the xml.  For example.  There's a tutorial about [Defining Custom Attributes](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) which states, "it's possible to read values from the AttributeSet directly" but it doesn't say how to actually do this.  It does warn, however, that if you don't use *styled* attributes then:

- Resource references within attribute values are not resolved
- Styles are not applied

If you want to ignore the whole styled attributes thing and just get the attributes directly:

example.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:custom="http://www.chooseanything.org">

  <com.example.CustomTextView
    android:text="Blah blah blah"
    custom:myvalue="I like cheese"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note there are two lines of xmlns (xmlns = XML namespace), the second is defined as xmlns:custom.  Then below that custom:myvalue is defined.

CustomTextView.java

```
public CustomTextView( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
{
  super( context, attrs );
  String sMyValue = attrs.getAttributeValue( "http://www.chooseanything.org", "myvalue" );
  // Do something useful with sMyValue
}
```

Answer (score 6):

AttributeSet is the set of properties specified in an xml resource file. You shouldn't have to do anything special in your custom view. The `View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` gets called to initialize a view from a layout file. Just add this constructor to your custom view. Check out the [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html) example in the SDK to see it used.

Comment: Not sure if the examples links ever showed the actual examples, but they always redirect to the same page. What I always do is refer to the same example from the samples folder in the SDK. For example, the example cited above is present in the folder `android-sdk\samples\android-17\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view`

Answer (score 0):

When a view is created from an XML layout, all of the attributes in XML tag are read from the resource bundle and passed to view's constructor as an `AttributeSet`

Although it is possible to read values from the `AttributeSet`directly, doing so has some disadvantages:

- Resource reference within attribute values are not resolved
- Styles are not applied

Instead pass `AttributeSet` to [`obtainStyledAttribute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,%20int[],%20int,%20int)). This method passes back `TypedArray` array of values that have been deferenced and styled.