# How can I set TextColor, TextSize of PagerTitleStrip from code?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**I am trying to set the textsize and textcolor from the pagertitlestrip and cannot find a way to do it.**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/myStrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**EDIT**

main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        style="@style/PagerTitleStrip"
        android:id="@+id/myStrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="PagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/PagerTitleStripTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="PagerTitleStripTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Pity that i didn't found a way to make it from AttributeSet, get a Resource NotFound or InvalidResource Exception.

Comment: Do you want to set only those attributes for the text in the `PagerTitleStrip`?

Answer (score 32):

`textSize` is not available directly as XML property of `view.PagerTitleStrip`.

However I managed to set it up indirectly using the **style** attribute as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    style="@style/viewPagerTitleStrip" <-- added style attribute here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
     />
```

Then I defined the `textSize` in **styles.xml** as follows:

```
<style name="viewPagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item> <-- my desired text size
</style>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is the best way!

Comment: @Андрей - This is working. And demands the "Correct Check" as the correct answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 10):

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html

Set the color value used as the base color for all displayed page titles:

```
void setTextColor(int color)
```

Set the default text size to a given unit and value:

```
void setTextSize(int unit, float size)
```

looks like a no-brainer.

```
PagerTitleStrip titleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.titleStrip);
titleStrip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24);
```

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this question really late, but as of now, textSize though not in the prediction option, works.

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

Comment: Still works perfectly in Android Studio 3.2.x running on Nugat image and in 2019.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look in [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java?av=h#PagerTitleStrip)

```
final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);  
final int textColor = a.getColor(1, 0);  
final int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(2, 0);
```

Comment: `public PagerTitleStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
 super(context, attrs);
 (...)
}` Any example to create **AttributeSet** for PagerTitleStrip ??

Comment: you can only create it from xml, look in 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html 
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316686/what-is-attributeset-and-how-can-i-use-it
also helpfull http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/util/AttributeSet.java#AttributeSet

Comment: i wrote this: `XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.mypagertitlestripattributes);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

pagerTitleStrip = new PagerTitleStrip(this, attributes);

pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.myStrip);` and the xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <item name="android.R.attr.textAppearance">@null</item>
 <item name="android.R.attr.textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
 <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</resources>` but nothing changes no crash no exception

Comment: Do you have a PagerTitleStrip in xml layout?

Comment: But you ask in title to do it from code. look in sources of PagerTitleStrip for attributes names and put them to layout. Also look in you code above! You did very easy mistake

Comment: AttributeSet can only from code be created and PagerTitleStrip don't have android:textSize or android:textColor even from code there are no setter for size and color. How to do it from an xml file i don't know. No one of your links shows me an example how the xml file should look like for the PagerTitleStrip.

Comment: look in attributes color and dimensionPixelSize

Answer (score 0):

textsize, text color not applied to tab. My code is as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"`enter code here`
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```