# Multiple if statements

Tags: java, android, performance, button, if-statement

Hypothetically let's say I'm using one if statement to account for ten different possible button presses that send an event value to an event listener:

```
public boolean onTouch(int v) { //this is my only listener for all ten buttons
  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   if(v==button_one){pool.play(bass1, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_two){pool.play(bass2, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_three){pool.play(bass3, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_four){pool.play(snare1, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_five){pool.play(snare2, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_six){pool.play(snare3, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_seven){pool.play(hh1, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
   if(v==button_eight){pool.play(hh2, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);}
 }
 return false;
}
```

Would it be more efficient to categorize these? say... one onClick event for snares and one for basses and one for the hi hats so that when a button is pressed the program doesn't have to count through each if statement, only the one's that are within the listener for the fired event?

Comment: I prefer this way, 10 different listeners for something so simple seems excessive.  You can probably do else if so all the other lines aren't evaluated once you've found the button.

Comment: But doing so, does the handler gets a call for `onTouch` events in other elements?

Answer (score 5):

What about something like this?

```
HashMap<int,int>  soundMap = new HashMap<int,int>();
soundMap.put(button_one, bass1);
soundMap.put(button_two, bass2);
soundMap.put(button_three, bass3);
soundMap.put(button_four, snare1);
soundMap.put(button_five, snare2);
soundMap.put(button_six, snare3);
soundMap.put(button_seven, hh1);
soundMap.put(button_eight, hh2);
```

Have the HashMap as a class variable, and have the mapping initialized in onCreate or something. Then you can just use this for your listener:

```
public boolean onTouch(int v) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        pool.play(soundMap.get(v), 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The benefit of this is that if you have to add more buttons in the future, you only have to modify the map initialization method with the new sound mapping; the listener will not require any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the rich vein of advice and opinions here, and agreeing with all before about "is it really a performance issue", I would go for the structure which makes the code easiest to read and maintain to you, and anyone else who might need to maintain it.  With maintenance, think also about extending it.  What happens in 3 months when you want to add 5 more sound pads?

Reducing to the minimum number of lines may give you some almost immeasaruble performance boost and save a few bytes in your APK but in most cases, I'd trade that for readability.

All that said, I do like kcoppocks' solution.  to me, it's short sweet and elegant and how I'd do it, but, if your level of experience differs and you can't just look at it and say "ah yes, I get it", then keep your ifs, or better, a switch.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about breaking that up until you know it's a problem.  A switch would help reduce the repeated `if` statement:

```java
public boolean onTouch(int v) {
  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (v) {
    case button_one: pool.play(); break;
    case button_two: pool.play(..); break;
    ...
    }
  }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: The Feedback speed of this website amazes me. I think I'll go with the switch statement as the option then if I decide to load more files, if it won't matter then i'll be able to relax about it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

It's not really worth worrying about performance in this case; the time taken for the conditional statement is going to be thoroughly dwarfed by the event handling code around it. The first through third laws of performance are measure, measure, measure, and I'm skeptical about the chances of finding a difference.

I can't help but notice that the only thing that changes is the first argument to pool.play. Is there a relationship between bass1, bass2, etc and the corresponding v values?

Comment: Nope, the pool is an array with all of the sound files loaded into it so whichever button you press depends on which file the pool plays. The first parameter is the only parameter relating to the audio files to choose from, the others are the volumes, loop setting, and float value, [I dont fully understand the float parameter yet]

Comment: There may be an interesting variation of @kcoppock's answer where you arrange for the pool's ids to be the same as those of the buttons. Alas: it would be the kind of trickery that's good for making you feel clever but much less good for maintainability. Mostly, what kcoppock said.

Comment: @Iain: I like the idea; that would be a nifty solution for sure. it'd be nice if you could add a tag in XML relating to the associated sound ID, but I don't know that there's a way to do that. @KendalH: The last float parameter is the playback speed. `1.0f` is 1:1 playback, you can go from `0.5f` (50% playback speed) to `2.0f` (200% playback speed)

Comment: I guess this has run it's course, but Kendal, it's really easy to extend a View class (your buttons) and add custom attributes to do whatever you want.  Just about the only rule is that you can express the value of the attribute in XML.  See this example for a starter...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316686/what-is-attributeset-and-how-can-i-use-it

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its necessary but i would definetly recomend switch and case. You can order as most common to least common but its such a small change that won't be noticed. It doesnt take very long at all to go through those if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many times this `if` runs, but it doesn't seem inefficient to me. This boolean test is very fast.
Anyway, if you do want to make it as efficient as possible, I see two options:

1. The easy one: use `else if` instead of `if`.
2. The complicated one: use an array of `ActionIf` objects to do what you want:

```
public interface ActionIf {
    public void go();
}

public class ActionBass1 implements ActionIf {
    @Override
    public void go() {
        pool.play(bass1, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public class ActionBass2 implements ActionIf {
    @Override
    public void go() {
        pool.play(bass2, 1f,1f, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

...

public ActionIf[] actions = {new ActionBass1(), new Action Bass2(), ...);

public boolean onTouch(int v) { //this is my only listener for all ten buttons
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && v >= 0 && v <= (button_eight-button_one)){
        actions[button_one+v].go();
    }
    return false;
}
```